# Firebase Crashlytics - Xamarin Android

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, crashlytics

It seems that this [package](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/Crashlytics) is not working for versions v71 of Xamarin.Firebase libraries.

I have tried all the steps still getting the error:
Fabric.Services.Concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: 'This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.'

Anybody knows how to make this work?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the google-playservices.json file? Which build action does it have?

Comment: Yes I added the google-services.json. Build action is 'GoogleServicesJson'.

Comment: Based on that error message, it seems you're using a very old package. Could you try updating to a newer version?